# TreeViewId.SelectedNode.Depth Equivalent in Javasacript

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax

In C# page i am getting `TreeViewId.SelectedNode.Depth`, while in javascript when i am trying to get depth of same treeView i am not getting the depth.

```
var treeViewData = window["<%=TreeViewMerchantId.ClientID%>" + "_Data"]; 
if (document.getElementById(treeViewData).selectedNodeID.value != "") 
{
   var selectedNode = document.getElementById(treeViewData).selectedNodeID.value;
   var text = selectedNode.innerHTML; 
   var Depth = selectedNode.depth; 
   var Lable = selectedNode.level;
}
```

Comment: Please mention your code where u are getting error..

Comment: In C# page i am getting TreeViewId.SelectedNode.Depth, while in javascript when i am trying to get depth of same treeView
i am not getting the depth.

var treeViewData = window["<%=TreeViewMerchantId.ClientID%>" + "_Data"];
            if (treeViewData.selectedNodeID.value != "") {
                var selectedNode = document.getElementById(treeViewData.selectedNodeID.value);
                
                var text = selectedNode.innerHTML;
                var Depth = selectedNode.depth;
                var Lable = selectedNode.level;

Comment: you can edit your page and put that comment there... instead of here....

Comment: var selectedNode = document.getElementById(treeViewData).selectedNodeID.value;  you should have to put it like this

Comment: i Have edited the code please check

Comment: _Data Is Used To Get Data of TreeView.

Comment: How u r getting there???